# Hibernate возвращает null вместо сессии

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

Уже и не знаю, на что подумать.
Хочу с базой H2 и Hibernate написать, что нибудь простое. Создал проект, в maven прописал dependecy
Написал конфиг, hibernateutil, а в итоге получаю null при попытке получить сессию. Хотелось бы понять в чем может быть причина

P.S:

Другой проект, который я создал за пол часа до этого с таким же конфигом и классом HibernateUtil работает нормально и hibernate создает мне в корне проекта папку mem с файлом БД...
Написал конфигурационный файл hibernate.cfg.xml с следующим содержимым

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

<session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:mem./test</property>
    <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
    <property name="connection.password"/>

    <property name="hibernate.default_schema">PUBLIC</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

    <mapping class="Author"/>

</session-factory>
```

Написал класс HibernateUtil в котором создаю сессию

```
public class HibernateUtil {
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

static {
    final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .configure()
            .build();
    try {
        sessionFactory = new MetadataSources(registry).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

И так же простенький pojo Author с использованием lombok

```
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Author {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String second_name;
}
```

Делаю попытку создать pojo и сохранить его в классе App

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try (
                Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()
        ) {
            Author author = new Author(1L, "Vasya", "Pupkin");
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(author);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

И вместо файла базы данных с таблицей и сохраненной в ней записью автора получаю NullPointerException:

```
янв. 12, 2021 8:52:35 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.27.Final
янв. 12, 2021 8:52:36 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager 
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
янв. 12, 2021 8:52:36 PM             
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()" because     
the return value of "HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()" is null at App.main(App.java:8)
```

Даже структура проекта все в одном package...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не уверен, что в тему, т.к. настройки через xml, maven, H2 и session не использовал, однако приведу вот такой пример из практики: На сервере, куда деплоилось приложение БД не инициализировалась из-за наличия уже запущенного в том же Tomcat приложения. Лечилось это проставлением разных значений в конфиге: `spring.jmx.default-domain=ТУТ_УНИКАЛЬНОЕ_ДЛЯ_ПРОЕКТА_ЗНАЧЕНИЕ` https://stackoverflow.com/a/37134550/3212712

Comment: Да в том то и дело, там нечему мешать...
Ни сервера, ни Spring. Голый hibernate и смешнее всего, что другой мой проект точно так же созданный работает, а этот нет. Вот я и не могу понять в чем дело. В процессах ни где ничего не весит, что могло бы мешать

Comment: А вы в логи смотрели? Вижу, что у вас в HibernateUtil игнорируется ошибка в catch блоке. Может, если её в логи вывести что-то прояснится?

Comment: Вы совершенно правы!
Истина все гениальное просто.
вывел в лог, увидел Could not load requested class : org.h2.Driver
По запросу в гугл нашел, что надо у dependency на h2 убрать
<scope>test</scope>
Хотя dependency копировал с mvnrepository и она шла сразу с данным scope..
В общем, после удаления все заработало. Спасибо вам! Помогли:)

Comment: Рад был помочь) Можете комментарий в ответ перенести - так он будет лучше виден будущим посетителям вопроса)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ был на поверхности и прост.
Как мне верно подсказал Юрий с выводом ошибки в лог стало очевидно, что дело в зависимости.

Ошибка гласила

```
Could not load requested class : org.h2.Driver
```

Дело в том, что сам mvnrepository.com предлагает зависимость на H2 с test

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.200</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

А данный scope виден только во время тестирования, по этому и обычный запуск ничего не давал. После удаления данного scope все заработало.
P.S.: Будьте внимательнее)